# Raster Coordinates after Geoferencing

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing, alignment

I have an orthophoto output from drone deploy that is out by about 3m. When I try and georeference the raster using QGIS georeference tool, my raster disappears to the other side of the planet.

Original raster data:

Coordinate Reference System (CRS)
Name    EPSG:28355 - GDA94 / MGA zone 55
Units   meters
Method  Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM)
Reference   Static (relies on a datum which is plate-fixed)

```
Properties
Extent  479798.9668961506686173,7866566.4490122618153691 : 479961.5290583146852441,7866795.2158455923199654
Width   8157
Height  11479
Data type   Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
```

After georeference:

```
Coordinate Reference System (CRS)
Name    EPSG:28355 - GDA94 / MGA zone 55
Units   meters
Method  Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM)
Reference   Static (relies on a datum which is plate-fixed)


Properties
Extent  -24075223.5517620444297791,-395316947.7120478153228760 : -23665921.7186154648661613,-394740954.6088616251945496
Width   8157
Height  11479
Data type   Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
```

Note the radical differences in Extents?

Just trying to move it 3m.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you adding georeference points? Using ground control points or by clicking on the map canvas using a reference image? try make sure reference image is in same projection, and that the QGIS project is also in same projection.

Comment: I am using map reference tool. Reference is Google Sat. CRS for site is EP28355. Google Sat is operating from EPSG3857. I am using Google Sat as Reference Map but I can't select EPSG3857 as the project is in 28355. Should I try do the project in 28355?

Comment: I would try playing around with CRS settings. e.g QGIS Project CRS, target CRS in the reference tool. Perhaps match the target CRS with the reference image CRS.

Also, if you didn't use ground control points with DroneDeploy, the misalignment won't be equal across the whole image. The GPS of the drone is only accurate within a few meters (assuming it doesn't have RTK). You will have to add a lot of georeferencing points to account for this distortion depending on the size of the image.

Comment: Have you considered to use Affine transform for offsetting the image by 3 meters? Or is the need for a shift not uniform?